# Create a file object from raw binary information in Python

Tags: python, file-io, python-imaging-library

#### Question

What is a clean way to create a file object from raw binary information in Python?

#### More Info

The reason I need to do this is because I have the raw binary information comprising a jpeg image stored in ram. I need to put it inside some kind of file object so that I can resize the image using Python's [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/about.html) library.

According to the [pillow documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html), the file object needs to implement the `read()`, `seek()`, and `tell()` methods.

```
The file object must implement read(), seek(), and tell() methods, and be opened in binary mode.
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o Someone else, or yourself, can claim the rep by elaborating with an answer, but these should be what you need. Cheers.

Comment: I suspect [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) will do help you -- maybe `tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a mention of how to handle this situation under the documentation for `PIL.Image.frombytes`:

```
...If you have an entire image in a string, wrap it in a BytesIO object,
 and use open() to load it.
```

This is what I ended up with that worked using `BytesIO`:

```
import io
import PIL
from PIL.Image import Image

file_body = <binary image data>
t_file = io.BytesIO(file_body)
img    = PIL.Image.open(t_file)
```

Note: The comments mention `tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile`. This seems like it should have worked, but it did not for some reason.